# Как useEffect вызывает новый рендер компонента?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Использую реакт-роут. Вопрос простой и сложный одновременно. Есть страничка с формой авторизации и навбар с защитой роутов. При не авторизированном пользователе в навбаре 2 ссылки, при авторизированном - 4. Теперь самое интересное - когда пользователь авторизируется навбар перерисовывается и показывает 4 ссылки, отлично. Но пользователь остаётся на страничке входа, как сделать редирект? Второе - когда пользователь выходит из системы навбар не перерисовывается и приходится нажимать на F5 что бы увидеть 2 ссылки. [GitHub](https://github.com/DmitriyTanase/test-react-control-panel.git)

**навбар:**

```
export function Navigbar() {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        Authentication();
    });

    function Authentication() {
        setCurrentUser(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
        console.log(currentUser);
    }

    function LogOut() {
        localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
        console.log('deleted:' + localStorage.getItem('userToken'))
    }


    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Control panel</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    {currentUser ? (
                        <div className="container">
                                <li className="nav-item ">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/additem">Add item</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item ">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/edititem">Edit item</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item ">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/deleteitem">Delete item</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item ">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/" onClick={LogOut}>
                                        <span className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"/>
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className="container">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                                    <span className="fas fa-sign-in-alt"/>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/listOfItem">List of items</Link>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

**форма логина:**

```
export function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        getToken();
    });

    function onChangeUsername(e) {
        setUsername(e.target.value)
    }

    function onChangePassword(e) {
        setPassword(e.target.value)
    }

    function getToken() {
        console.log(username, password);
        const token = Date.now().toString();
        if (username && password) {
            localStorage.setItem('userToken', JSON.stringify(token))
        }
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('userToken'))
    }

    return (
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <div className="card card-container">
                <form onSubmit={getToken} noValidate>
                    <span className="fas fa-sign-in-alt"/>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control"
                               name="username"
                               value={username}
                               onChange={onChangeUsername}
                               placeholder="Login"
                               required
                        />
                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                            Wrong username
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={onChangePassword}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            required
                        />
                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                            Wrong password
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Submit form
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moжно не делать отдельный роут на логин, а как-то:

```
<LogInDialogOrProtectedContent content={ grants => ....SomeSecretList.... }/>
```

---

На login/logout можно и страницу reload-ить на всякий случай.

А случаи бывают разные:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation

---

Надо понимать, что основная проверка прав на что-то все равно должна быть на сервере, т. к. с клиента можно, при желании, послать любые запросы.

`content={ grants =>` в аргумент callback, чтоб не рендерить то, что не будем показывать.

Comment: Да, Вы правы проверка конечно должна быть на стороне сервера. Но меня сейчас интересует совсем другое. Как мне вызвать рендер?

Comment: "не делать отдельный роут на логин" подходит?

Comment: "когда пользователь выходит" "делать reload()" подходит?

Comment: Конечно оба варианта подходят, но как не делать отдельный роут на логин я не понимаю. То есть сделать какой-то общий роут и в этом роуте разместить `<Switch/>` показывающий `LoginDialog` или `ProtectedContent` в зависимости от `userToken`? В моей голове пока что рождаются плоские решения задач, и я просто не вижу Ваше решение. Второй вариант с релоадом подходит, я даже пытался делать его но синтаксис подвёл, думал что достаточно убрать `e.preventDefault` и стр будет перезагружаться. Вообщем погуглю синтаксис `reload()`. Спасибо

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: По сути -- если часть роутов открыта, каждый роут может просто сам отображать логин по условию. И показывать 4 ссылки всем.
С `HOC` будет просто меньше писанины.